# Maximum Filesize of JavaScript Files in Firefox

Tags: javascript, json, firefox

I have a pretty big JavaScript file containing JSONP data (27 MB) which is loaded via script tag. This works in all browsers except Firefox, which refuses to load the file (error is "switch statement too large", although there is no switch in there). It works for smaller files (2MB) though.

What is the maximum filesize of JavaScript files in Firefox, so I can partition the file and circumvent this border?

Comment: It is complete non-sense to load a client side script of 27 MB.

Comment: On what OS? 32 Bit/64 Bit? Version of FF?

Comment: Is `switch statement too large` the exact error information?

Comment: Have you tried to optimize the JS with Google Closure or to find error via JS Lint?

Comment: Have you tried, not to download the JSON but integrating it into the HTML itself?

Comment: the json file contains video information to be drawn on a canvas element. error occurs on win 7 64bit, Firefox 12 32bit version.   `switch statement too large` is the exact error information.

Answer (score 3):

I've only seen this error once a time after killing the streaming of a large JavaScript file from a website I can't remember at this time.

Is there any reason why you have to load the full file at once?
For example, you could stream it in 2MB parts, surrounded by something like

```
(function() {
    myJsonData += "..... 2MB of your code ...";
})();
```

**Note**: You have to define `myJsonData` in the global context to keep track of it!

After this you only need some finish statements and a callback, i.e. ship your last piece of data like this:

```
(function() {
    myJsonData += "..... 2MB of your code ...";
    // Trigger callback which works with the json data
    myCallbackFunction();
})();
```

Thats the way i would try to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`I think max is 20MB

```
(function() {
    myJsonData += "..... 2MB of your code ...";
    // Tr`enter code here`igger callback which works with the json data
    myCallbackFunction();
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

some tests about mobile browsers - can be interesting to check also on desktops : script size vs script in browser cache

http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2010/07/12/mobile-cache-file-sizes/

Answer (score 0):

or to bypass limits and slow loading : just compress the data (one time on the server); clients' browsers read the file and uncompress it.

both function in about 70 lines of code :

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/LZW_compression#JavaScript